# Use main app UIViewcontrollers in third party framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, applozic

I would like to use NSObjects and UIViewcontrollers from my main app in a linked framework. To be more specific, it is th [Applozic](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-iOS-SDK) chat framework, and I would like to open and use data from the main app in this framework.
Could anybody point me to the right direction?
If I try to use a view controller from the main app, it will display a symbols not found error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MapDisplay", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ALLocationCell.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

The idea is to open my own map view controller when a location message is tapped. And I would like to check some user settings to see if the user is eligible for sending messages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is very vague type error caused due to various reasons, try following

- Try to add ALLocation.m file in your compile sources  or add your all ".m" files
- Applozic framework might be not **linked** properly. Check framework
  in "Link Binary With Libraries" in project's build-phase tab.
- If your are using cocoa pods make sure your target's build settings
  contain $(inherited) in the other linker flags section.
- If *you importing some other project* in XCode and if current and
  import project both have same files in Compiler source then just
  **remove same file in current project** in "Build phase' settings.
- some macro in any view controller which is calling the files you've already deleted.The app will not show any errors until you build your app, it will throw the error in compilation phase in .o files.Remember to delete any MACRO that's calling to files you've already deleted.
- Might be missing the **Core Data** framework or any which library is using and your project not including like **Core Location** in Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries